# CudaMalloc not allocating to shared GPU memory on Ampere micro-architectures in opposite to Turing

Tags: c++, memory, cuda, nvidia, cudatoolkit

I am using CUDA Toolkit 11.8 - operation system - Windows. 
The program is compiled on Windows with Nvidia T1200. 
I use CMAKE 3.15.7 with flag:

```
CMAKE_CUDA_ARCH_BIN: 3.5 5.0 5.2 5.3 6.0 6.1 6.2 7.0 7.2 7.5 8.0 8.6 8.7 8.9 9.0
```

## Problem

When I run the code on my laptop (T1200) I can see, that `CudaMalloc` allocates memory first on **dedicated GPU memory** and when there is no more space available there, it automagicaly allocates data to **shared GPU memory**.

When the same code is run on RTX 3070 `CudaMalloc` allocates memory first on **dedicated GPU memory**, but when it is full it no longer allocates data to **shared GPU memory** but it reports `cudaErrorMemoryAllocation`

And I don't understand why the behavior on separate GPU-s is different.

I build the program on the laptop, than copy exec file to the machine with RTX 3070 and execute program there.

## The code

*Working Google Test Example*

```
class CudaTestMemory
{
public:
    unsigned char *cudaBuffer;
};

TEST_F(Cuda, cudaAllocator)
{
    CudaTestMemory *costBuffer[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        costBuffer[i] = new CudaTestMemory();

        size_t allocatedMemory = 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // 1GB
        cudaError_t cudaStatus = cudaMalloc(&costBuffer[i]->cudaBuffer, allocatedMemory);

        if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess)
        {
            // we failed - cannot allocate XXXX GPU Memory
            costBuffer[i]->cudaBuffer = nullptr;
            throw std::runtime_error(cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        }
    }
}
```

### Result on NVIDIA T1200

NVIDIA T1200 has 4 GB of GPU dedicated memory + 32 GB of shared GPU memory (computer RAM). The test crashes there on iteration number 34 when there is no more space available on GPU (device + shared)

### Result on NVIDIA RTX 3070

NVIDIA RTX 3070 has 8 GB of dedicated memory + 128 GB of shared GPU memory (computer RAM). The test crashes there on iteration number 7 when there is no more memory on GPU (just device).

Comment: Where do you take the "128 GB" from? Is that just your system RAM? Because discrete GPUs don't have that kind of shared memory like iGPUs. In the context of CUDA the term "shared memory" stands for on-chip scratchpad memory of which there is 46 SMs * 100KB per SM = 4.6MB on a 3070 and you can't allocate that memory via `cudaMalloc`. You can make some amount of system RAM available to the GPU via `cudaMallocHost` (See [Page-Locked Host Memory](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#page-locked-host-memory)) not sure if that will help, as it is comparatively slow.

Comment: Shared memory is the amount of RAM memory on the machine

Comment: There is also `cudaMallocManaged` but it is much less usable on Windows than on Linux, where one can use it to oversubscribe device memory with a paging mechanism.

Comment: This is an artifact of WDDM behavior, and doesn't have much to do with CUDA directly.  WDDM manages memory allocations on the GPU in each of these cases, and WDDM implements a virtual memory system.  That means that in some cases, WDDM will allow you to allocate more than the physical ram that is available on the GPU itself.  It does this by making use of system memory in some fashion.  I'm not aware of any guarantees that WDDM will allow you to use "all" or "most" of system memory in this fashion, and I'm not aware of any details on how to control this behavior.  It is mostly outside of CUDA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in comments, CUDA on WDDM Windows machines functions differently than other operating systems, in that the WDDM subsystem handles GPU compute memory allocation and scheduling, rather than being handled by the CUDA runtime as on other platforms.

The Windows GPU memory virtualization functionality is a property of Windows rather than CUDA, and there isn't anything that you can do in CUDA user code to change its behaviour. You can read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/gpu-virtual-memory-in-wddm-2-0).

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a fix for this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Shout-out for @paleonix and robert-crovella who also commented on this topic. Now I understand the problem and I can address actions to solve the problem :)